# Several endpoints in pom

Tags: maven, soapui, pom.xml

I define endpoint for test project in pom. For two test suite I use different endpoints.
Test suite 1 - endpoint 1
Test suite 2 - endpoint 2
How to define, that endpoints should be differ for test suites in pom?

Comment: Is that you cloned a suite and running against another endpoint?

Comment: I should run one test suite with one endpoint on jenkins, secont suite with other endpoint.

Comment: The question is are the test cases in side the test suite1 and testsuite2 are same except that those differ in endpoint alone?

Comment: No, test cases are different.

Comment: You can use this https://www.soapui.org/functional-testing/properties/working-with-properties.html#4-Example----Centralized-Endpoint just make two properties.